# determinant of higher order for skew symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image] 
For a skew symmetric matrix of higher order . how do we find the determinant in short cut

Comment: In general, you do not. However, in this case your luck is having a skew-symmetric matrix of odd order: what's $\det(-A)$ ?

Comment: Hint: $A = -A^t$, then $\det (-A) = (-1)^n \det A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Det(A)=Det({A^T})=Det(-A)= Det(-I\cdot A) = Det(-I)\cdot Det(A)=(-1)^5Det(A).$$

We deduce $$Det(A)=0. $$

Comment: Smart work . and I was labouring out. :-)

Comment: ...from this we see that for all **odd** $n$ det. of sk.-sym. m. is equal $0$.